# How to build my own blockchain

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, bitcoin

I have been doing some theoretical reading on blockchain security for a while. To improve myself in this field, I want to develop a small-scale laboratory environment with my own computer and an old computer. For this, I previously tried to install go-ethereum (geth) but it didn't work (I haven't tried Go-bitcoin!). The reason it didn't work was because they discontinued PoW support in 1.11. I encountered many problems while trying to adjust the versions of many things during the installation phase, so I gave up.

What I need:

1. I need to be able to join this blockchain from another computer.
2. It should work in PoW structure.
3. I should be able to work on smart contract security & vulnerabilities.
4. I should be able to experience Double spending, Sybil, Eclipse, 51% attacks. (The necessary node, hash power is not a problem).

My question to you is, is there any resource documentation technique you can recommend for me to do this?